# Slim Framework: Configuring AWS Load Balancer to Securely Accept Requests without Insecure Middleware Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, slim, aws-application-load-balancer

I am using the Slim Framework in combination with AWS EC2 instances and an AWS Load Balancer to handle incoming traffic. However, when trying to access the application over HTTPS through the Load Balancer, I encounter the following error:

```
Message: Insecure use of middleware over HTTP denied by configuration.
```

I am seeking guidance on how to properly configure the AWS Load Balancer and Slim Framework to handle HTTPS traffic securely without compromising security by using the `insecure` setting.

Any advice, tips, or explanations on the correct setup and configuration to achieve this goal would be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!

To resolve this issue, I tried adding insecure="false" to the Slim Framework configuration, which allowed the requests to pass through without the error. However, I want to ensure that my Load Balancer is securely handling the requests, and I don't want to bypass the security feature by using insecure="false".

My goal is to configure the AWS Load Balancer and Slim Framework in a way that HTTPS requests are securely accepted by the Load Balancer and forwarded to my EC2 instances running the Slim application without triggering the "Insecure use of middleware over HTTP denied by configuration" error.

Comment: Have you tried to create an HTTPS listener, by deploying at least one SSL server certificate on your load balancer?